# Output multiple VM's to only 4 IP addresses ESXI

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, virtual-network

I have set up a computer as an ESXI environment.  The system has 1 physical network port.  When I create network ports on my virtual machines, each gets an IP address assigned by my router.  I need to limit the number of IP's assigned by my router to the system to 4.  Is it possible to set up a virtual network that could allow groups of VM's to be routed to individual IP's for my router (and do port forwarding and such on the individual VM routers)?

My goal is the picture below:

[image]

If this is not possible, what sort of hardware would be needed in order to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why not pass IP's direct to endpoints? Give us some more background to help with an answer.

Comment: I am at a university and a wired connection gives me public IP's.  Each user has to register a mac address for each device, and the total devices is caped.  I want to limit my IP usage, but still have more that 1 (using a single router).

Comment: The Router that is listed is that yours or the Uni's? I would say just put a router between your network and there's and it will solve the issue.

Comment: The router listed would be the universities.   If I put a router between, I would only get 1 public ip.  I would need 4 routers and 4 network ports to get the 4 ips

Comment: Can you not use NAT why do you NEED 4 public IPs?

Answer (score 2):

The only way I see this being possible is to have multiple virtual firewalls i.e. Pfsense running in the middle. Each of the four Pfsense firewalls would have one ip from your router on what would normally be the WAN side, and can give off any number of "internal" its on its LAN side. This will allow your network to be something like follows:

Router using `192.168.0.0/24`

Pfsense_One with a WAN IP of `192.168.0.2` serving `10.0.0.1/24` on it's LAN
Pfsense_Two with a WAN IP of `192.168.0.3` serving `10.0.1.1/24` on it's LAN
Pfsense_Three with a WAN IP of `192.168.0.4` serving `10.0.2.1/24` on it's LAN
Pfsense_Four with a WAN IP of `192.168.0.5` serving `10.0.3.1/24` on it's LAN

This setup allows up to 255 machines connected to each of the pfsense virtual firewalls, for a maximum of 1020 machines that can be connected to your physical router using only four IPs from your physical router.